# Lens keeps on zooming a tad bit and lens error

Tags: lens, canon, error, powershot

So my family got a Canon Powershot sx220 HS 9 years ago. It was a great camera and had lived that full 9 years.

When we got a new camera and left the camera in its place my dad decided to give it to me to do  some photography. Then our baby got a hold of the camera, (*when the lens was zoomed in all the way*) and pushed the lens hard. Everything was fine but after turning it off the problem started.

The lens did retract but only on the non zoomed in place (*where it did zoom out but stayed on its normal place whenever you turn on the camera*) and then the pop up message "Lens error shut down automatically restart camera" was displayed.

The next day when i turned it on, it zoomed in a tad bit and then after some time, the error message returned.

When i shake the camera i hear something shaking. I tried every method but it wouldn't work.

So can someone please help me with this problem.

Comment: Probably time to buy a new (or used in good condition) camera - I'm not sure getting a 9 year old point-n-shoot camera repaired would be financially sound...

Comment: "*When i shake the camera, i hear something shaking*" That put a smile on my face.  **Now it is a baby rattle !**

Answer (score 4):

From your description, it appears your baby broke some relatively delicate part in the lens mechanism -- possibly a gear tooth or sensor part.  Given there is no practical or cost-effective option to repair cameras in this class (a repair would cost as much as replacement due to the cost of skilled labor), the only suggestion I can make is to take the Powershot out of service and replace it.

It appears this Powershot model is still offered, and you may also be able to get a good working one for less on eBay or from a used equipment dealer such as KEH.

Comment: Throw the camera into a bin for when your baby is 1.5 or 2. That's what we did and our little girl loves playing with our junked cameras and phones. It's even better that they still (kind of) work.

Comment: and since film is cheap for a digital camera, she can take lots and lots of photos whilst developing his photographic chops!

Comment: Well I do have a Sony Handycam DCR DVD610 but the battery was broken so I am waiting for the new battery. Now I know why the repair cost was 462 dollars. Thanks for the help!